# Magento 2 Reports Refresh Statistics Cron

Tags: magento2, cron, reports

Is it possible to refresh report statistics via cron job. Does Magento2 support refresh via cron feature out of the box?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it is possible.

First, pass "reportTypes" argument to your cron class by using di.xml like below

```
<type name="Vendor\Module\Cron\CronFile">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="reportTypes" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="sales" xsi:type="string">Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Order</item>
                <item name="tax" xsi:type="string">Magento\Tax\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Tax</item>
                <item name="shipping" xsi:type="string">Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Shipping</item>
                <item name="invoiced" xsi:type="string">Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Invoiced</item>
                <item name="refunded" xsi:type="string">Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Refunded</item>
                <item name="coupons" xsi:type="string">Magento\SalesRule\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Rule</item>
                <item name="bestsellers" xsi:type="string">Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Bestsellers</item>
                <item name="viewed" xsi:type="string">Magento\Reports\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Product\Viewed</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
```

Then, in your cron file,

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Cron;
use Magento\Reports\Model\ResourceModel\Refresh\Collection;

class CronFile extends Collection
{
    protected $logger;
    protected $reportTypes;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactory $entityFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface $localeDate,
        \Magento\Reports\Model\FlagFactory $reportsFlagFactory,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        array $reportTypes
    ) {
        $this->logger = $logger;
        $this->reportTypes = $reportTypes;
        parent::__construct($entityFactory,$localeDate,$reportsFlagFactory);
    }
    /**
     * @return $this
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

        try {
            $codes = $this->loadData();

            foreach ($codes->_items as $codek=>$codev) {
                $objectManager->create($this->reportTypes[$codek])->aggregate();
            }
        } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
            $this->logger->critical($e->getMessage());
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
           $this->logger->critical($e->getMessage());
        }
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did it work for you ?

Comment: Yes, it works perfectly for me.

Comment: @Sarasranglt, Doesn't it work for you?

Comment: worked fine (+1)

Answer (score 0):

where exactly do I put these 2 files.
I use the luma theme directly in
/[webroot]/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma/

Thanx. Thomas.